# Django: Hide request from runserver stdout

Tags: django

When running my django instance with

```
python manage.py runserver -v 0
```

I get each request made to django, replicated to the stdout despite the fact that I have set verbosity to 0. Is there any way to remove this info from being printed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
python manage.py runserver > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Comment: That would hide anything. I would like to be able to print (diagnostics info) in the stdout and just exclude the request.